# Why does illustrator keep grouping my paths when i want to merge them into one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

No matter what I do, when I select two paths in the layer window, and i use pathfinder to either unite them or merge them, they always turn into a group containing the same 2 paths i tried to merge. But want I want to to merge them into one path.

Why is it not working for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine paths with Pathfinder. It doesn't work that way. In fact, Pathfinder typically doesn't work well with open paths *at all*.

That being posted... Pathfinder does have an annoying tendency to create a group of the objects selected fro its operations. merely ungroup after the pathfinder operation if you don't want the group.

Comment: So then how can i merge multiple paths into one without turning it into a group?

Comment: @relisys it really depends upon what you are trying to do.. but `Object > Join` will connect the end points of paths. You **can't** "combine" or "merge" paths in the middle of other paths. Again, that's not how Illustrator works.

Comment: That is exactly what im trying to do. I want to merge two overlapping paths one on top of another. If I cannot do that with paths, could you tell me what I can do with my current paths to achieve this goal? Should I convert them to something else?

Comment: You can expand (`Object> Expand`) stroked paths to *shapes* and then Pathfinder *will* combine shapes. But future editing will require you to adjust shapes, not stroked paths.